# D3 TickFormat to Display ISO Week number

Tags: d3.js

d3 (4.11.0)

I have an x axis which displays the week number at the start of each week. Is it at all possible to display the ISO week number?

Currently my x axis is defined as follows:

```
this.xAxisTertiary
            .ticks(d3.timeMonday.every(1))
            .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('Week %W')); // Week 16
```

I read here ([API Reference](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format/blob/master/README.md#isoFormat) that `%V` would format the week number as an ISO week number, but perhaps I am missing something.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The %V format option was not added until d3 v4.12 ([change log](https://github.com/d3/d3/releases/tag/v4.12.0))

Otherwise your code should be fine:

```js
var width = 500;
var height =400;

var svg = d3.select("svg")
  .attr("width",width)
  .attr("height",height);
  
var g = svg.append("g");

var parse = d3.timeParse("%B %d, %Y");
var domain = [parse("January 1, 2017"), parse("January 1, 2018")]


var x = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain(domain)
    .range([10, width-10]);


g.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(10,150)")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
        .ticks(20)
        .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("Week %V"))
     )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.12.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. Upgraded to v4.12.0 and it all worked fine. Thanks also to Mike Bostock for the addition of ISO Week numbering, great new feature.